# Android Launching the Calender from my application and recieve the new appointment

Tags: android, android-intent, launching-application

I have an application "ApplicationX" and when I click on a button I will see the create appointment view from the Android Calendar, here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("title", "Sometitle");
        intent.putExtra("description", "Somedescription");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

That works fine. So now I save the appointment and I'll back in my activity. To get the appointment results, I tried:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        extras.getString("title");
    }
}
```

But this IS NOT WORKING. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this problem? I have almost the same. I want get ID of created event. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508511/calendar-event-intent-startactivityforresult

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_EDIT` is not designed to work with `startActivityForResult()`.

In your case, `ACTION_EDIT` would seem to be wrong in general. You are not trying to edit an existing appointment, you are trying to create a new one. `ACTION_INSERT` would seem to be more appropriate, and `ACTION_INSERT` *is* designed to work with `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: It's not working. Now I can't see the android calender app. What is wrong??